# Running Flash in chrome extension popup window

Tags: google-chrome, flash, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

How can I use flash in chrome extension?
I am writing a chrome extension that will extract a flash game and run it in a popup window.
The game can run on normal web page as there will be a prompt to enable flash.
However, in the popup window, there is no prompt to enable flash.
I tried using embed, but it is not working. If directly put the flash src in URL, it will be downloaded.

It seems that after chrome 62, there is no option to always enable flash.
The extension is still working if the google account has using the extension before.
But for new user, the flash is disabled.

Comment: Can you post your manifest? I think this line should make it work "permissions": [
          "contentSettings"
        ],

Comment: Permissions are displayed for tabs and the popup isn't a tab. Open a separate html page from your extension in a new tab, add the flash object there so when the permission is granted it'll be [hopefully] remembered for the entire origin of your extension including the popup.

Comment: Grant permission in tab doesn't affect the one in the popup, I have tried.

Comment: You've probably tried it in a content script which runs in a web page origin, not in the extension's origin.

Comment: Yes, the origin is the same. But flash don't work even if I browse the web page in the popup window.

Comment: Seems like this extension can play flash on the popup, but I just don't understand why it works. Trying to reference its method to play flash.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flash-player/bmimdmkleccdoghpgdhaahkelfhjfhgm

Answer (score 0):

When I made an extension to load Flash games, I didn't know about contentSettings, all I did was have a page open on install that told the user to add the permission in manually (click a button and then paste something into the Flash settings page - chrome://settings/content/flash).

It used [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) to copy the chrome extension url into the clipboard.

I think you could do a much better job than I did at explaining, and you could probably also save to chrome.storage that the user did or didn't go to the flash settings page, so that you could control alternative content on your popup.

```
//background.js
...
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
    if (details.reason == 'install') {
        chrome.tabs.create({active:true, url:'firstinstall/firstinstall.html'});
    }
}
...



//firstinstall.html
    ...
    <h3>There is just one thing you need to do to set this thing up</h3>

    <p id="p1">When you click the button, <code id="ex"></code> will be copied to your clipboard</p>
    <p id="p2">A new tab will open that will go to Chrome's flash settings page</p>
    <p id="p3">All you need to do is <strong>click Add (next to Allow), paste(<code>Cmd+v</code>) in the URL and click Add</strong></p>

    <br>

    <label id="btn" class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#ex">Click me</label>

    <br><br>

    <h4>And that's it!</h4>
    <p>Click the extension icon in the toolbar to get started</p>

    <script src="../libraries/clipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="firstinstall.js"></script>

//firstinstall.js
    var z = document.querySelector('#ex');
    z.innerText = chrome.runtime.getURL('/')

    new ClipboardJS('.btn');

    var y = document.querySelector('.btn');
    y.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: 'chrome://settings/content/flash'});
    }, false);
```

Comment: It seems that chrome://settings/content/flash don't have any setting to enable flash for extensions, and the new chrome version can only set to ask first but cannot always enable.

Comment: Yeah, in Chrome 69-70 I think you can disable chrome://flags/#enable-ephemeral-flash-permission to get the manual input back, but 71+ I haven't found any way of allowing it